# What is the significance of trees under which rivers flow in Heaven?

Tags: quran

There are many verses in Quran which promise gardens in which rivers flow. Like:

> 4:13 - These are the limits [set by] Allah , and whoever obeys Allah and
>   His Messenger will be admitted by Him to **gardens [in Paradise] under
>   which rivers flow**, abiding eternally therein; and that is the great
>   attainment.

or

> 47:12 - Indeed, Allah will admit those who have believed and done
>   righteous deeds to **gardens beneath which rivers flow**

or

> 4:57 - But those who believe and do righteous deeds - We will admit
>   them to **gardens beneath which rivers flow**, wherein they abide
>   forever

So what's the significance of these gardens? Is there anything special about them? Can we assume that these promises are only appealing to the people who lived mostly in droughty deserts at that time?

Comment: +1 for `Can we assume that these promises are only appealing to the people who lived mostly in droughty deserts at that time?`

Answer (score 1):

The environment mentioned in Qur'an as Jannat (garden) is not constructed yet. It will be heavenly environment for valuable and precious people in future. Thus talking about it in current language and culture is like talking about current modern environment in culture and language of a caveman even more far away. So it is our current and retarded culture that may interpret it as an appealing promise for people dwelling in deserts. So we should wait while image to be clearer as Qur'an says ([Al-an'am:6/67](http://quran.com/6/67)):

> لِّكُلِّ نَبَإٍ مُّسْتَقَرٌّ ۚ وَسَوْفَ تَعْلَمُونَ
>
> Every tiding has its time appointed; you will surely know.

Answer (score 1):

Asalamu 'aleykum. 
In the name of Allah the Most Gracious the Most Merciful.
 Firstly, phenomenons in Heaven are unlike anything here on earth that we know of. The logic in heaven is unlike any logic here on earth. So to answer your question. No, we can not assume that this is what Allah intended for us to understand because if these gardens, Allah speaks about in Quran, under which rivers flow, were only to be pleasing to people that live in dry areas, then this would contradict the whole purpose of the garden.

Therefore we can not  assume this. We should take it for granted that however these rivers are, they are ultimate perfection. They are unlike any river in our wildest dreams. We can not speak of things in jannah with our limited worldly mind. The prophet(peace and blessings be upon him)  told us that, there are things in Jannah that no eyes has ever seen, no ear has ever heard and no mind can comprehend. It may be, and Allah knows best, that Allah is using this simple language with us to make our peanut heads comprehend jannah, but these rivers are not as we think. And even if they are rivers of water, we wouldn't be able to imagine how something simple like water would be like in the pure gardens of jannah.

The entire awesomeness about Jannah is in such a way that even simple things like soil is extremely, unimaginably,breathtakingly pleasurable to behold. That it would take a long time for us to find it okay not to look.

For example, we all know how soil looks like and smells like and feels like when mixed with water and how it gets our hands dirty if we play in it. Now, Allah made this logic of soil on earth as we know it now. The same thing in jannah is different all together. The prophet s.a.w tells us that it is made of pure white musk. Now try to imagine a soil made of musk and gems and rubbies? It's still soil but in a pure form.

I was listening to an amazing lecture a while back about jannah and the sheikh said, may Allah rest his soul, that the palaces in jannah will be one on top of another, not beside each other, not opposite each other, one on top of the other. So on one castle is somehow suspended another.  Is this  even comprehensible??. He also said that the silver cups will be made of colorless silver. Now how in the world is silver colorless? Get my point. That logic we just have not reached yet.

So we accept what Allah says in the Quran that there are gardens and under these, rivers flow. We understand that these gardens and these rivers are knowledge of the unseen but we believe they are a reward for the pious, God fearing and patient. And we must accept that nothing in jannah is a joke, as i said earlier the simplest thing on earth like a headscarf is better than the world and everything in it like the prophet s.a.w said about the cloth that is on the houses head.

Jazaka lahu qeir
Allah knows best.

Answer (score -2):

Rivers in paradise are not only water and have different streams: water, honey, milk, special wine

Also water itself has high value and because we have used to have water available everyday we forget its value.

They are only examples of what are in paradise. Other verses there is anything you wish.

> The Noble Qur`an points to four kinds of liquid that flow in four
>   different riverbeds in heaven: the river of water that quenches
>   thirst; the river of milk that satiates hunger; the river of honey
>   that gives pleasure and strength; and the river of wine for
>   happiness.[353]  These liquids have been created in such a way that
>   the passing of time does not corrupt them. In other verses an
>   indication is made to a drink called “Rahiq Makhtum”[354] or that
>   which is mixed with camphor[355] or zanjabil[356]. In one verse
>   mention is made of a pure drink[357] that the Lord will give; the
>   saqi, or cup bearer, being Allah (awj) himself.

---

**Reference:**

- [www.al-islam.org](http://www.al-islam.org/faith_reason/43.htm)

Comment: Your answer does not make sense at all. According to Quran, there is no hunger and thirst in Heaven: **20:118: Indeed, it is [promised] for you not to be hungry therein or be unclothed. 20:119: And indeed, you will not be thirsty therein or be hot from the sun.**

Comment: @Meysam yes in heaven but not at judgement day for all. in fact water is reward of some good deeds in life. the river is not for water only. there is river of wine, milk, honey,..

Comment: Again your answer is irrelevant because the verses I quoted are about heaven not judgement day.

Comment: @Meysam it was partially irrelevant. answer improved